# ClientCertRequest cannot be resolved how to fix?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm new to cordova, And just starting to build my project in eclipse. When I finished the installation of some prerequisites for cordova and creating my project, I loaded my cordova project on eclipse and I got this error. ClientCertRequest cannot be resolved and I dont have any idea to solve this, I look to any tutorial top try different approach of installation and importing project but it seems the same as I posted here. Can anyone help me. I've been working this error for a long hour. [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this helps.

1. right click on `Cordovalib`
2. click on `properties`
3. choose Android
4. choose a `Target` name whose API level is >= 21

Also, make sure you have these APIs Installed from your Android SDK manager.